# How difficult would it be to invade Mainland China during WWII?

Tags: warfare, alternate-history, geography, history

In an alternate history WWII scenario, the Republic of China became a fascist, one-party state similar to Nazi Germany (who they're closely allied with; Adolf Hitler IRL even considered the Chinese honorary Aryans), with the warlords, communists and other enemies having been eradicated. By 1942-43, they have decent technology and military personnel in the tens of millions.

Once Hitler is defeated and Germany surrenders, the Allied Powers (including Japan, but that's another story) plan to defeat China and its fascist regime, but how difficult would it be to do such a feat during this time period? How many Allied soldiers would be needed, how long would the invasion take, what factors could lead to China surrendering, etc?

EDIT: In this timeline, the Empire of Japan never invaded Manchuria (again, another story for another time), and has become less imperialistic and more industrialized. America also has nukes by this point but hasn't used them. These include Little Boy and Fat Man.

Comment: Japan did invade mainland China in the 1930s.

Comment: What's the status of imperialism on the Asian mainland? If Britain, France, and Japan have their respective colonies (particularly Manchukuo) their invasion will be quite a bit easier than if they're struggling to secure a foothold a la Normandy.

Comment: The detail about a less-imperial Japan is good, but there are a lot of relevant details you haven't addressed.  For one, who has nukes, and how many?

Comment: China mainland is very vulnerable from attacks from the north ("around the mountains"). They build this Wall for a reason. So if you plan to invade , not to nuke them out - USSR position is very important. It would be the major force in the play.

Comment: You’ve fell victim to one of the classic blunders! The most famous is never get involved in a land war in Asia, but only slightly less well known is this; never go in against a Sicilian, when death is on the line!

Comment: @Separatrix "Never get involved in a land war in Asia"?  But there have been tens, hundreds, and probably thousands of land wars in Asia, many of which were clearly won by one side or the other instead of being draws.  I'm sure that hundreds of states, mostly Asian states, have won land wars in Asia.  And in the 1940s it would be partially an air war in Asia.

Comment: @M.A.Golding, you have a classic film to watch.

Comment: Republic of China is already a fascist regime IRL at that time. The only reason Germany choose Japan over China is Germany's internal politic. And how are you going to deal with Mao's communist guerilla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on exactly how your story handles the warlords, China would be comparable to Russia, only more so. A latecomer to industrialization, with **plenty** of internal challenges, but a sufficiently tyrannical leader might get a remarkable industrial growth, *percentage-wise*, since he is starting from such a low level. And lots and lots of inefficient industry might amount to something. But perhaps not much. Consider the industrial parts of the Great Leap Forward, how they [worked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Leap_Forward#Industrialization) and how they [failed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Leap_Forward#Backyard_furnaces).

So if you're writing a halfway realistic alternate history, China might have been something like Russia, minus the war losses but also minus lend-lease. Call it a decent tank design, built in the low five figures. A decent fighter and ground attack plane, also in the five 
figures. But no strategic air force, no battleships or carriers.

Getting Japan in isn't all that difficult, by the way. They were *quite* close to the UK during WWI. Have them step in providing escorts in the Atlantic and not just in the [Mediterranean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Japanese_Navy_in_World_War_I#Operations_in_the_Mediterranean_(1917-18)), and there could be *Japanese destroyers protecting US troopships during 1918.* From that foundation, they'd be much more friendly rivals.

- Hitler's "admiration" for non-Aryans was in direct proportion to their distance from Germany and their usefulness to his plans, cf [Bose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhas_Chandra_Bose).
- Despite the [Atlantic Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_Wall), Germany was unable to defeat an invasion "at the beaches." It depended on counterattacks which were made impossible by Allied air power. China would be even worse placed to counterattack, given the state of rails and roads. (If you posit a greatly improved rail net, something else suffers. Tanks? Aircraft?)
- No amphibious invasion is necessary if the attackers come overland from Siberia or the southern coast. The US and UK might still use landings, but China would have to deploy major mechanized forces to watch the back door.

Comment: China main logistic network up to 1950's were water chanels: you literally can get from almost any village of China to any other village by water. RL China utilised it a lot during WWII and after that. USSR support was delivered  to Mao by this way . And this support included tanks and bombers  - all were delivered by water lines.

Answer (score 2):

**Very difficult.**

After WW2, there was no appetite for another war. The general mood of the Allies was that of [rebuilding, recovering and ensuring it never happened again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aftermath_of_World_War_II). The public of both the US, UK and other allies would never be swayed to start another large war.

The mood was such that the UN was established with the strong mandate [to prevent further conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_aggression). It would make little difference if China at the time was Fascist rather than Communist. To answer your question directly - in order to invade **you already have the troops, the weapons and the means to achieve war, but not the motive and the support to do so.**

Keep in mind that during (and indeed, prior) there was in many ways more concern in the [US for Communism than for Fascism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascism_in_North_America). The 'truce' with the Soviets during WW2 was begrudging, and in many ways only for convenience. As the Berlin Wall went up, lines in the sand were drawn, immediately after WW2. But even then there was no 'war', (Cold War excepting) and that was against a *communist* nation.

It is worth noting that after the Cultural Revolution (and retreat of the republicans), China became a One Party State. The only difference was the label 'communist' instead of 'fascist' - which the distinction being fascism is based on strong racial or national identity, in lieu of communist 'centralist' identity. The distinction in your context is small, as both situations are essentially still single party states.

So in summary, for Republics and Democracies to invade another country, even a Fascist one, after the dust has settled in WW2 would require leaders and public opinion to be for another war, which it was decidedly was not.

Comment: I agree with point of this asnwer (jast take fascist Spain asan example), but this quiestion requers concreet answer. An number. "N million troops" -what is N?. I do not know how many american and pro-american forces were in china war after WWII ended (and wich lead to appearance of Taiwan state), but that a good starting point.

Comment: I think the scenario is less "WW2 is over, now let's invade China" and more "for whatever reason, the Axis is Germany/Italy/China, how does the end of the Pacific Theater play out?"